# What does 파리한 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

It's from a novel. I know it doesn't mean flies and I have no idea:

**파리한** 얼굴에, 겁이 많았다.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which is, one of the literary words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [this](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=en&entryId=3cf73302b6934b1e9adcdf2e4eb3071d&query=%ED%8C%8C%EB%A6%AC%20%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4) meaning of *파리하다* - ashen, pale, pallid, white.

> 파리한 얼굴에, 겁이 많았다.

His/her face went white with fear.